# i need one rest url i need to perform delete operation using rest api i need client code my code is this

Tags: java, spring

@RequestMapping(value = "/RemoveOneSubject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView RemoveOneSubject(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

```
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("RemoveOneSubject");

    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/subject/api/remove/{id}";


                String id = request.getParameter("id");
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.delete (uri,id);

                model.addObject("theSubject", id);

            return model;


enter code herejsp is
```

Delete

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Created by</th>
                        <th>Created time</th>
</td></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <c:if test="${not empty theSubject}">
                    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${theSubject}">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkBox"></td>
                        <td><a href=""><c:out value="${listValue.name}" /></a></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listValue.createdBy}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${listValue.createTime}" /></td>                      
                        <td><c:out value="${listValue.studentID}"></c:out></td>                     </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. And hint : that preview window exists for a reason. You want us to spend our time to help you with your problem so you please spend the time it takes to write a well formatted human comprehensive question.

Answer (score 0):

for the delete. in RestController there is already have **Delete Method**.You can actually use **Get Method** for easy way, not best practice. But, you can use this code to delete something throughout your controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class ApiCodeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/delete")
    public string DeleteSomething(@RequestParam(required = false) String email)
    {
        //Do Something with your code to delete an object
    }
}
```

You just need to call it.

```
/api?delete=your-parameter
```

Hope its gonna help.

Comment: i need to perform delete one row from jsp page using rest url what are the changes required in jsp